# Shell Script to count the number of files coming in a directory

Tags: shell, unix

I have the following scenario -

A remote server(say, Server1) pushes some files into another server(say, Server 2), using FTP.
It then updates the database at Server2 and then pushed files are deleted automatically. The files remains in the directory for just few seconds.

I have to write a **SHELL SCRIPT** which will count the number of these files coming in the directory (say in minutes).

PS : Server1 and Server2 are on the same network path

Comment: Without knowing what FTP server you're using and what OS you're running it on, this is going to be very difficult to answer.  More than likely, one should read the xfer log for the FTP server or hook into the process which consumes the directory rather than directly polling the incoming directory.

Comment: You may parse FTP logs, or use notify-tools if you're on linux

Comment: @dannysauer/sshilovsky - it is requirement to write a shell script for the same. I'll try to do what u have suggested.
Its a linux server and is running on solaris.

Comment: Do you have `inotifywait` from `inotify-tools` available?

Comment: @cdarke - I think No. Could you please let me know how to use them and from where could I get those from.

Comment: You would have to install these onto the server that the files arrive on.  They allow you to monitor changes to a directory as they happen.  Just Google `inotify-tools`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will count the files modified during the last minute.

```
find / -mmin 1|wc -l
```

Run it every minute.

Mount network drives with [ftpfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/FtpFs) or [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/).

*Update:* If you fear to loose some files during a seconds fraction you can use the time stamps of files. You have to touch two files in oder to find those files newer than `t0` and older than `t1`.

Initialize the start time:

```
touch t0
```

After that you can execute this in a loop:

```
touch t1
find / -newer t0 -a -not -newer t1 | wc -l
mv t1 t0
```

This makes sure that you do not loose any files.